# DSolve does not give solution

Tags: differential-equations

No answer is given when I evaluate the following expression:

```
p[x_,t_]:=D[h[x, t], x]
DSolve[{
  D[h[x, t], t] == 11120 D[h[x, t], {x, 2}] + 0.000625,
  h[60000, t] == 10,
  p[0, t] == 0,
  (h[x, 0])^2 == 45100 - 0.0000125 x^2
}, h[x, t], {x, t}]
```

Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Does it have a symbolic solution?  If not, try `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your definition of `p`. Try, for instance, what evaluating `p[0, t]` gets you:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you define it, it only works if you call it with undefined symbols. Calling it with the value of 0 in the `x` slot effectively evaluates

```
D[h[0, t], 0]
```

which is obviously nonsense.

It is better to define it using `Derivative`:

```
p[x_, t_] := Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t]
```

which doesn't depend on x being symbolic. Less elegant, but just as effective and perhaps more educational is this alternative:

```
p[x_, t_] := D[h[x1, t], x1] /. x1 -> x
```

`Dsolve` still doesn't solve your problem symbolically and `NDSolve` has problems with the way your initial and boundary conditions are specified. Rewriting the equations as follows helps:

```
sol = h /. First@NDSolve[{
     D[h[x, t], t] == 11120 D[h[x, t], {x, 2}] + 1/1600,
     h[60000, t] == 10,
     p[0, t] == 0,
     (h[x, 0]) == Sqrt[45100 - 1/80000 x^2]}, 
    h, {x, 0, 60000}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]